# How to store a variable with command status [shell script]

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am searching a word in a file through grep command. Now I need to store the status in a variable V1 with 0 or 1. how can i do it?

```
tail -n 2 test.s | grep -q "FA|"$(date "+%m/%d/%Y")
tail -n 2 test1.s | grep -q "FA|"$(date "+%m/%d/%Y")
tail -n 2 test2.s | grep -q "FA|"$(date "+%m/%d/%Y")
```

If the above searching word is found then variable V1 value should be 0 else 1.

file content :

```
keytran|20160111|test.s
submKeyqwqwqw|NDM|Jan 11 01:34|test.s|6666666|sdgdh-RB|ltd.ET.CTS00.act
loadstatus|thunnnB|6666666|FA|01/16/2016|01:34:57|01/16/2016
|01:37:13|load|test.s
```

please suggest

Comment: mind sharing contents of test.s?

Comment: Have a look at this entry http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command. I tried to execute your command with a garbage test.s and later executed echo $?, I got 1. So I think you should make an assignment like x=$? after executing your greps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your shell, after each command execution the status of the previous command is available in a special variable: bash family `$?`, csh family `$status$`:

```
#/bin/bash
tail -n 2 test.s | grep -q "FA|"$(date "+%m/%d/%Y")
V1=$?
```

or

```
#/bin/csh
tail -n 2 test.s | grep -q "FA|"$(date "+%m/%d/%Y")
set V1=$status
```